# Using filters and wildcards to find incorrect records on SQL server management studio

Tags: sql, sql-server

New to using SQL server management studio...

Just trying to filter my table results to show only records that have (deceased) in them...

So far I have

```
select SURNAME, count(SURNAME) from [dbo].[blahblah] group by SURNAME order by SURNAME
```

I would usually use `TRIM`/`translate` like the below, however it doesn't recognize these functions

```
select trim(translate(cast(GUAR_PHONE as string), '0123456789', ' ')),GUAR_PHONE
from atable
WHERE trim(translate(cast(GUAR_PHONE as string), '0123456789', ' '))<>'';
```

Comment: If I am not mistaken transate is an Oracle function and not a SQL Server one. I think the equivalent T-SQL one is `REPLACE`.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  Your code seems to have nothing to do with your question about finding `DECEASED`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for a string such as `'deceased'`, then you would use `like`:

```
select b.*
from dbo.blahblah b
where b.guar_phone like '%deceased%';
```

This seems to address the question at the beginning of the post.  I have no idea what the code is supposed to be doing.

In SQL Server, if you just want to see if there are any non-numbers in the string, you would do:

```
where b.guar_phone like '%[^0-9]%'
```

Comment: I think his code is an example from (oracle) on how he'd normally replace numbers with empty string to see if there's non-numbers in it.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thankyou very much, will mark as correct once 7 mins has passed <3

Comment: Marked as correct as promised... one question when I try the [^0-9] it just brings up all records.

Comment: How would I do the same but for letters? [^A-Z]?

Comment: Sorted! Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to check whether there is a non-numeric character in you column,
use IsNumeric function..

```
select y.*
from dbo.YourTable y
where ISNUMERIC(y.guar_phone) !=1
```